# Strong convexity of quadratic function

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Assume that $Q$ is a positive definite matrix, is it true to say that the function
$f(v)=v^TQv$ is strongly convex with respect to the norm  $||u||=\sqrt{u^TQu}$?

Thanks

Comment: I think yes, as matter of eigen values determined by Q

Comment: Yes, That's my intuition too, but I can't prove it

Comment: Why ? Just try with Hessian Matrix

Comment: The Hessian will work only for the euclidean norm no?

Comment: write down the Taylor expansion of $f$ and you will see.

Comment: Apply a change in basis, and this amounts to the question of the convexity of $f(x) = x^Tx$ with respect to the usual norm, $\|x\| = \sqrt{x^Tx}$.

Comment: What definition are you using for strong convexity with respect to a norm?

Answer (score 5):

Let $\lambda \in [0,1]$, $v_1, v_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $0 < Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. Denote ${\bar \lambda} := 1 - \lambda$ and $\|v\|^2 := v^T Q v$. Then, 
\begin{align}
f(\lambda v_1 + \bar \lambda v_2) 
&= \lambda^2 \|v_1\|^2 + {\bar \lambda}^2 \|v_2\|^2 + 2\lambda \cdot {\bar \lambda} \cdot v_1^T Q v_2 \\
&= \lambda\, \|v_1\|^2 + {\bar \lambda} \, \|v_2\|^2 - \lambda \cdot \bar \lambda \cdot \Big ( \|v_1\|^2 + \|v_2\|^2 - 2 v_1^T Q v_2 \Big ) \\
&= \lambda\; f(v_1) + {\bar \lambda} \; f(v_2) - \lambda \cdot \bar \lambda \cdot \|v_1 - v_2\|^2.
\end{align}
Therefore, $f(v) = \|v\|^2 = v^T Q v$ is strongly convex (with respect to $\|v\| = \sqrt{v^T Q v}$).