# Is this strongly convex?

Tags: calculus, optimization

$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^\intercal W x$, where $W$ is positive definite, not necessarily the identity matrix. $\nabla^2 f(x)=W$. Is $f(x)$ strongly convex with the parameter $m={}?$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1367642 This may help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strong convexity of $f$ with parameter $m$ is [equivalent](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/708575/43949) to $\nabla^2 f(x) \succeq m I$, so in your case, $f$ is strongly convex with parameter $m$ being the smallest eigenvalue of $W$.